# Lotus Notes - Embedded View - Show Single Category not behaving

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a page with an Embedded view with a Show Single Category formula set to `@Name([CN]; @UserName)` and the First column of the view a field that is the 'Assigned To" Person which is [CN] of the various staff.  This works great to show each person their own assignments as you would know if you have used this feature.

Because the person's name (1st Column) does NOT show, I repeat their name as the 3rd column [catergorized] (the 2nd column in the view is a counter of assignments).  This way, the person sees their name and has comfort the list is their own assignments.

Good thing, because I have this problem being reported.  In the following circumstances, BUT NOT consistently:  When closing a document which returns the the view; when opening a new category in the view (let's say column 4); when refreshing the view > The Embedded view now shows the assignments of the person above or the person below this person alphabetically or has gone completely blank.  In all cases, choose a new view from the menu (outline) and return to this `My Assignments` view and it is corrected.

Has anyone seen this and have ideas for me?

Thank you

Comment: I have seen this happening occasionally in different databases, but unfortunately have no idea how to fix this

Comment: I've seen things like that when the view is sorted by a column other than the single category.